Is a separate tag (differential-calculus) needed?
The tag differential-calculus was created several times in the past - almost always removed relatively quickly.1
The most recent incarnation was created in April 2024. This one still exists.2

We already have tags such as calculus, derivatives and multivariable-calculus. (And for some more advanced topics, there are gateaux-derivative, frechet-derivative.) Is a tag differential-calculus needed?
Would it be reasonable to create a synonym differential-calculus $\to$ derivatives? This would prevent the tag from being created again and again.
If the preference is to have a separate tag called differential-calculus, what would be the content of this tag and how would it differ from the already existing tags?

1I have listed the past questions which had this tag in the Tagging chatroom. (At least the ones I was able to find.)
2At the moment, it is still listed among the new tags. See also here.

I would support creating the synonym differential-calculus $\to$ derivatives.  If this response has more upvotes than downvotes in a week or two, do exactly that.
